# Python in Raspberry socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use when creating socket

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I'm creating a simple server to receive message from outside network
When I run the following code in raspberry:

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((Host, Port)) 
s.listen(5)
print ("Server is running\n")
c, a = s.accept()
print (addr, " is now connected! \n") 
data = recieveData(s, c, a)
```

after running like 10 seconds, the server is terminated with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I don't recall stop the server ungracefully by pressing Ctrl C, and even that I did, I've waited for the server to release it, or even using ps -fA | grep python and kill the running processes, but none of these works. It still has the error? I cannot change the port as it's the required port for the program.
Does anyone having any idea how to fix it? I'd be really appreciated.

Comment: Try this command: `$ lsof -i :6283` to see if it's used by another process..

Comment: using lsof -i :6283 doesn't show anything in my command line.

Comment: I saw that thread but somehow couldn't apply to my project...

Comment: Put this line `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` right after `s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)` and you should be good

Comment: Then it should be as: `s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`

Comment: Why you have both:  import socket and from socket import * ?

Comment: IT WORKS. Thank you Iron First. you're awesome!